# What is "detached" instances in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails

What are detached intances in grails. ?

Please explain with an example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

When you create a new domain class instance (e.g. `def u = new User(username: 'me')`, Hibernate doesn't know anything about it. But when you persist it, e.g. when you call `save()`, Hibernate pushes the insert to the database and associates it with the current Hibernate Session (not to be confused with the HTTP session - they're completely different).

Also, when you load an instance from the database, either individually or as part of a list of multiple results, you get access to the instance but it's also associated with the current session. These objects are "attached" to the session.

This is useful in several ways. One is as a first-level cache. When you call `get`, e.g. `def user = User.get(123)`, it's retrieved and attached. But if you call `get` again with the same id, it's retrieved from the cache and there is no extra database call needed. Another is dirty checking. Hibernate also caches the original data that was retrieved, so when you modify one or more fields it can know what (if anything) has been changed.

One place where objects becoming disconnected is a problem is lazy loading. It's common to store objects in the HTTP session, but once the Hibernate session closes (e.g. at the end of the request) all objects that were attached become detached. If you have a lazy-loaded instance or collection that's not initialized, and later retrieve the instance from the HTTP session and try to access the lazy data, it will cause an exception because the instance is disconnected and cannot connect to the database to retrieve the lazy data. One fix for this is to re-attach the instance to the current session - see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html. The better fix is to not store objects like this in the session, but instead store the id only, and reload the instance when it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that it is no longer associated to a Hibernate session.

Answer (score 0):

A new instance of a a persistent class which is not associated with a Session, has no representation in the database and no identifier value is considered transient by Hibernate:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Foobar");
```

// person is in a transient state

A persistent instance has a representation in the database, an identifier value and is associated with a Session. You can make a transient instance persistent by associating it with a Session:

```
Long id = (Long) session.save(person);
// person is now in a persistent state
```

Now, if we close the Hibernate Session, the persistent instance will become a detached instance: it isn't attached to a Session anymore (but can still be modified and reattached to a new Session later though).

All this is clearly explained is the whole Chapter 10.  [Working with objects of the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html) that I'm only paraphrasing above. Definitely a must read.